# Some terminology: differences of term, formula, and expression in logic?

Tags: logic, terminology, computer-science, predicate-logic

In the wikipedia article on [logical terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(logic)) it is written:

> In analogy to natural language, where a noun phrase refers to an
>   object and a whole sentence refers to a fact, in mathematical logic, a
>   term denotes a mathematical object and a formula denotes a
>   mathematical fact. In particular, terms appear as components of a
>   formula.

I am not sure to understand exactly what that means, and the exact difference between:

- a term
- a formula
- an expression

If authors adopt different conventions, I would like the standpoint of one that makes a clear distinction between the terms. In particular things that are not clear not me are questions like:

- is every term a formula?
- is every term an expression?
- is every formula a term?
- is every formula an expression?
- is every expression a term?
- is every expression a formula?

Examples of things that are terms, formulas, and expressions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Syntax) is a "name": variables and constants are terms.

In addition, "complex" terms can be manufactured using function symbols.

Example: $n$ is a variable, $0$ is a constant and $+$ is a (binary) function symbol.

Thus, $n,0$ and $n+0$ are terms.

[Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Formulas) are statements.

Atomic formulas are the basic building blocks for manufacturing statements.

They are formulas that have no sub-parts that are formulas.

They are manufactured using *predicate* symbols, like e.g. $\text {Even}(x)$, equality and terms.

Thus, $\text {Even}(n), 0=0$ and $n+0=n$ are atomic formulas.

With connectives and quantifiers we can write more complex formulas, like: $\forall n (n+0=n)$ and $0=0 \to \forall n (n+0=n)$.

*Expression* can be a "generic" category: it may mean a string of symbols.

We may call well-formed expression a string of symbols that satisfies the rule of the syntax.

If so, it is either a *term* or a *formula*.